# When I run code with NumPy imported it does not run

Tags: python, numpy

```
'''The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?'''
import numpy as numpy

a = 0
primeFactors = []
def findPrimeFactor(num):
    global a
    global primeFactors
    while numpy.prod(primeFactors) != num:
        if a%2 == 0 and a != 2:
            a =+ 1
        else:        
            d = num/a
            if isinstance(d, int) == True:
                primeFactors.append(a)
                a =+ 1

findPrimeFactor(13195)
print(primeFactors)
print("Bok")
```

I imported NumPy after I installed everything propertly (pip, python, NumPy). I also added everyting to Path. Code is not running in VSCode, Idle and also not in Sublime Text 3. I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, `isinstance(d, int)` will always be `False`, as the division between two ints will return a float in Python 3.8:
`a = 4`
`b = 2`
`c = a/b`
`isinstance(c, int)`
`>>> False`

Comment: @torresmateo do you know how can I fix it or if there is other way to check if number is integer?

Comment: @LovroPriselec problems like this can easily be tracked down with a debugger. A debugger is critical, day 1 knowledge for any programmer, so if you're not using one now you absolutely need to, since you're putting yourself at a huge disadvantage and creating a bunch of work for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop, `isinstance(d, int)` will always be `False`, as the division between two ints will return a `float` in Python 3.8:

```py
a = 4 
b = 2
c = a/b 
isinstance(c, int) 
# >>> False
```

to test this, you could use the modulo operator. Using the code above, you can see that `a % b == 0` is `True` (which is equivalent to `c` being an integer.